# Shifting array index position after values have been outputted

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, indexing

I am working on a program that mimicks the `BinaryReader.Readbytes()` method to compare data that I am extracting from Binary files. To test that that it is working properly I am writing a method that does mostly what the `ReadBytes()`method does. It is meant to read the specified number of values from an array and after that, start from the same index from where it last outputted values and get the next few values that are specified.

I currently have code that gets the specified number of values. However, when I call the method the next time, it starts from the beginning of the array again. I don't know where it might be going wrong. If you can help me out, that'd be great! Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
public class TestInformationHeaderData 
{

    private byte[] _data;
    int _index = 0;

    public TestInformationHeaderData(byte[] data) 
    {

        _data = data;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes(int count)
    {

        _index = count;
        var returnArray = new byte[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            returnArray[i] = _data[i];
            count++;
        }

        _index = count;
       return returnArray;
   }
}

TestInformationHeaderData test = new TestInformationHeaderData(b);
byte[] byteArray = test.getBytes(3); 
byte[] newByteArray = test.getBytes(1); 
//Here's where it starts reading from the first value again.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `_index`? It seems like you never consume the value.

Comment: The index is meant to keep track of the position where the array last outputted values from. Say, if the first 3 values from the array are outputted when getBytes(3) is called, the index is meant to help start reading from position 4 in the array when the getBytes() method is called again.

Comment: Post how you're calling the method `getBytes` - that's most likely the reason for what the issue.

Comment: @vpm That's what I was getting at. You never read the value of `_index` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @vpm - you need to edit your question and add the code there.  Code doesn't format in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the state correctly between calls, you need to actually read the value of index, otherwise storing it isn't useful. Something like below (untested):

```
public class TestInformationHeaderData 
{
        private byte[] _data;
        int _index = 0;

        public TestInformationHeaderData(byte[] data) 
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public byte[] getBytes(int count)
        {
            var returnArray = new byte[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                returnArray[i] = _data[i + _index];
            }
            _index += count;
            return returnArray;

        }
}
TestInformationHeaderData test = new TestInformationHeaderData(b);
byte[] byteArray = test.getBytes(3); 
// _index now 3
byte[] newByteArray = test.getBytes(1); 
// _index now 4
```

To make the code more complete you should add bounds checking as well.

Comment: Cool thank you so much! i get it now. Just tested it and it works too =).